# Upgrading Wildfly from 26 to 28 causes wrong base64 decoding?

Tags: java, base64, wildfly, decoding

the title sounds dubious but after upgrading wildfly from 26 to 28 the base64 decoding works differently of java.util.Base64.

I have the following Code:

```
var tokenString = "IVHDn15NMWdvJi3CpyREPEUlRCJBLmUldXEwJyY3QmI+dXR3JERjMWlyKSFPTDRCS3R1VzU8T1IzaDJMa15+diVzXkQ8cEI7OTBmfCstcHR1TFxRL3ViLGVsfkReKz95MGEvSsKnMmJSMHlsPi5iKD5WXklsdmIiPHBeUCtreHFfUzUiKiVpdzI1ImFlVS4+Rip4JVF0I21DbT9kMsKnVzYtLEpNRS06Uy5rNjZhJcKnUmo4bVXCpzte";
var token = tokenString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String tokenDecoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(token));
```

When I debug this on Wildfly 26 I get

```
tokenDecoded == "!Qß^M1go&-§$D<E%D"A.e%uq0'&7Bb>utw$Dc1ir)!OL4BKtuW5<OR3h2Lk^~v%s^D<pB;90f|+-ptuL\Q/ub,el~D^+?y0a/J§2bR0yl>.b(>V^Ilvb"<p^P+kxq_S5"*%iw25"aeU.>F*x%Qt#mCm?d2§W6-,JME-:S.k66a%§Rj8mU§;^"
```

and on Wildfly 28 I get

```
tokenDecoded == "!QÃŸ^M1go&-Â§$D<E%D"A.e%uq0'&7Bb>utw$Dc1ir)!OL4BKtuW5<OR3h2Lk^~v%s^D<pB;90f|+-ptuL\Q/ub,el~D^+?y0a/JÂ§2bR0yl>.b(>V^Ilvb"<p^P+kxq_S5"*%iw25"aeU.>F*x%Qt#mCm?d2Â§W6-,JME-:S.k66a%Â§Rj8mUÂ§;"
```

which is wrong and slightly different from the Wildfly 26 decoding. If I encode `tokenDecoded`  on Wildfly 28 back with

```
var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tokenDecoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I get `encoded != tokenString`.

I neither am switching between projects nor changing the java SDKs.

I am using the following SDK:

[image]

I don't understand why Base64 would have another way of decoding. Is there any configuration I am missing?

P.S.: Apologies for the token legnth. The token is a random generated String which is why it is so long.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I am missing something that is not related to the wildfly upgrade at all. But I would not know what is different, since I didn't change the code base.

Comment: This is probably because you're not specifying a character set when creating the string, and at runtime, a different default character set is used. It looks like your WildFly 26 runtime is using UTF-8, while your WildFly 28 runtime uses something like ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252. The solution is to use an explicit character set (i.e. `new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(token), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I have not thought of this at all.